# DataTable Not showing table

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.8

I am trying to incorporate dataTables to my posts index. i get the table to appear but there are no information shown in the table columns

I tried implementing the DataTables as their side says and i kept the normal way of displaying data just to be sure i get results

I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

For the creation of my table i use:

```
<table class="display" id="postsTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Slug</th>
        <th>Subtitle</th>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$post->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$post->Title}}</td>
            <td>{{$post->Slug}}</td>
            <td>{{$post->Subtitle}}</td>
            <td>{{$post->Content}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>


</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#postsTable').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

And i am sure i can get the results of my posts table since when i use:

```
<h1 class="title">Posts Table</h1>
<form action="/posts/create" id="myTable">
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <button type="submit" class="button is-link">Create New Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <li>
        <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">
            {{$post->title}}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

I get results.

Any help is appreciated as i couldn't find a working solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my code i realized that i had a typo on the names of the attributes i was trying to get. Instead of "Title" it should have been "title" and etc